# How to check if value is a Decimal?

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if value is a Decimal. I need do this manually preferably using re

Is this:

```
if re.match("^[0-9]*[,\.][0-9]*$", value) == None:
    print 'error!'
else:
    print "%.2f" % value
```

is correct?

value can be, for example:

```
20
30.1
155,69
```

How to do it?

Comment: In other words you'd like to check if a number is a number? `20 == 20.0`, which is a "decimal"?

Comment: Can you clarify *exactly* what you mean by "a Decimal", perhaps with more examples? What about `1.0e3` or `-1.0e-3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `+` quantifier here not `*` for the first digit string unless you want values such as `.30` also to make the `,.` optional use `?` and `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside character classes:

```
re.match("^[0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]*$", value)
```

Comment: why not .3? it is a valid number (on a calculator)

Comment: The title and the example make this question ambiguous, but accepting `.` is definitely not a decimal.